# how to switch to verbose output

Tags: snow-leopard, startup, shutdown

Using Debian linux, I can switch to verbose output during shutdown and startup by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>.

I already know how to startup in verbose mode using <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> but I would like to switch to verbose mode from non-verbose mode.

Is there some way to do this using OSX snow leopard.

Answer (score 1):

To boot into verbose mode use <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> on boot up.